# Scrolling when in portrait mode

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I've been looking around but still cant find any solution of enabling scrolling horizontally when the tablet is on a portrait mode.  My contents are all inside my scroll bar. Would really appreciate if some help could be given. XAML preferred.

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="764"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1353"
               VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" />
```

Read a little more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode) about this guy.

Also - what other controls are present that might affect this behavior?

Comment: I tried , anyway i only need the scrollbar when its in portrait. i have set the size to auto :\ still doesnt work. Its giving the rubber band effect

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are sizing your scrollviewer to fit landscape mode: the height of your control is 768px while the width is 1353px. So your scrollviewer is wider than your screen and is going off the edge.  Scrollviewer scrolls its contents, but it scrolls to the size of the control, not the screen.

So, when you transition to portrait view you will need to resize your control to fit the extents of the screen.  (Or possibly just making the scrollviewer auto-sized might fix your problem for now.)

Comment: I tried auto size, doesn't work >.< Any samples? Thanks!! :) It is scroll able but its like a rubber band which will pull you back to the original position

Comment: I have found that it rubberbands back if you set the scroll bar visibility to disabled.  Try 'hidden' instead?